# Trying to update Kodibuntu

Tags: updates, kodi

I just wiped an old laptop of mine and installed Kodibuntu on it, in order to use the laptop as a media center pc.  After installation I exited Kodi and logged into the desktop and opened terminal to update everything and when I run the sudo apt-get dist-upgrade command, it tells me that it is going to remove Kodi.  The whole reason I installed Kodibuntu was for Kodi.  How do I update without removing Kodi.  I am stumped on this matter and google didn't offer any help, so I'm hoping someone on here can help me out.

Thank you,
JohnDoeIII

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so Kodibuntu is off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

You may have to add the Kodi repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
```

Running that command should add Kodi to the list of recognized updatable items (aka repos).